# Метод с шаблонными параметрами реализовывающие интерфейс

Tags: c#, ооп, generics

Присутствуют:

- два интерфейса - номинально обозначим IRead и IWrite;
- шаблонный метод с сигнатурой

```
void <T>DoSomething(<T> innPar)
```

так вот - данный метод работает только с типами которые реализуют оба интерфейса.
Можно ли как-то указать это методу - что должно передаться только объект реализующий данные интерфейсы?
Поделитесь опытом в этом направлении.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
void DoSomething<T>(T innPar)
    where T : IRead, IWrite
{
    // ...
}
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/Pkfqyb